# Ranking changes according to their frequency

Tags: r

[image]

I am working on a school project where I need to create many graphs based on data from an Excel table and this is one of them

**D is a column in Excel**

```
library(ggmosaic)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)  
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)


######################################## - A - #######################################################

getwd()
setwd("C:/ZS (projekt)") # V případě potřeby upravte odkaz na vlastní pracovní adresář

data_ex = read_excel("C:/Users/zukov/OneDrive/Desktop/Pocitacove_hry.xlsx")


# Zjednodušme pojmenování proměnných.
colnames(data_ex)=c("ID","nazev","rok_vydaju","zanr","publisher","plat","pocitac_studium","soc_site",
                     "os","leg_software","ikb_znalost")


data_ex$zanr = as.factor(data_ex$zanr)

levels(data_ex$zanr)

data_ex$zanr = factor(data_ex$zanr,
                             levels = c("Sports/Racing","Simulation","Strategy","Role-Playing","Action","Shooter"),
                             labels = c("Sportovní/Závodní","Simulace","Strategie","RPG","Akční","Střílečka"))

# Určeme četnosti výskytu jednotlivých variant a uložme je pod názvem cetnosti_nom.
cetnosti_nom = table(data_ex$zanr)
cetnosti_nom # výpis absolutních četností

# V případě nominální proměnné je vhodné varianty proměnné seřadit dle jejich četností.
names(sort(table(dotaznik2$zanr),decreasing = D))

data_ex$zanr = factor(data_ex$zanr,
                             levels = names(sort(table(data_ex$zanr),
                                                 decreasing = TRUE)),
                             order = D)

cetnosti_nom = table(data_ex$zanr)
cetnosti_nom # Nyní jsou výstupem četnosti variant analyzované proměnné v požadovaném pořadí.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The decreasing argument needs to be `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  `decreasing = D` doesn't makes sense unless you've already defined `D` to be `TRUE` or `FALSE`.